# Qual é a diferença entre o "using" e o "using static"?

Tags: c#, sintaxe, using

Numa pergunta que fiz sobre C#, o @Maniero me respondeu e colocou um código de exemplo no DotNetFiddle.

O código é esse:

```
using static System.Console;

public class Program {
    public static void Main() {
        var objects = new [] {
            new {Id = 2, Nome = "Wallace"},
            new {Id = 4, Nome = "Cigano"}
        };
        WriteLine(objects.GetType());
        foreach (var user in objects) {
            WriteLine($"Meu id é {user.Id}");
            WriteLine($"Meu nome é {user.Nome}");
        }
    }
}
```

Percebi que no início do código há um `using static`.

Do que eu tinha aprendi até agora de C#, eu sabia que para facilitar o uso de uma classe que está dentro de um `namespace` específico, eu deveria usar `using`.

Porém percebi que, no exemplo acima, o @Maniero usou `using static System.Console` para chamar a função `WriteLine` sem ter que colocar `Console.WriteLine` em toda a chamada.

Qual é a diferença entre os `using` e o `using static`?

O `using` não funciona para classes? Só para `namespace`?

Qual é a finalidade do `using static` no caso específico?

Comment: Outro negativo? Há alguma coisa de errado com minha pergunta?

Comment: Parece que esquecem de positivar a pergunta, não custa nada.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Isto é possível à partir do C# 6. Pode-se usar o [`using static`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-directive?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) para importar classes estáticas ou membros estáticos de outras classes, assim todos seus membros públicos ficam disponíveis para uso direto sem precisa do qualificador da classe.

O `using` sozinho só importa `namespaces` e disponibiliza todos os tipos declarados nele.

```
using static System.Console;
using static System.Math;
using static System.Convert;
using static System.DateTime;

public class Program {
    public static void Main() {
        WriteLine(Round(ToDouble("123.45")));
        WriteLine(Now);
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/5TNPqo). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/TfyyYq). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Syntax/UsingStatic.cs).

Sem esse artifício:

```
using System;
                    
public class Program {
    public static void Main() {
        Console.WriteLine(Math.Round(Convert.ToDouble("123.45")));
        Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now);
    }
}
```

Tem situações que compensa usar, outra nem tanto. Também tem que pensar na consistência. Se abusar pode afetar a legibilidade. Tem caso aí que fica meio esquisito.

Note que é possível importar também partes estáticas de tipos que não são estáticos. Mas os membros de instâncias, por razões óbvias, não podem ser importados estaticamente, só são acessados pela sua instância.

Comment: Gostei, a versão 6 então facilitou as coisas.