# Como resolver um erro de formatação de string?

Tags: c#, .net, string, formatação

Estava programando normalmente no VS em modo "Console" quando me deparo com está mensagem:

> "A first chance exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
>   An unhandled exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
>   Additional information: Índice (baseado em zero) deve ser maior ou igual a zero e menor que o tamanho da lista de argumentos.
>   The program '[1124] ConsoleApplication4.vshost.exe: Managed (v4.0.30319)' has exited with code 0 (0x0)"

Do que se trata e como resolver?

**Código:**

```
string A1;
string A2;
string A3;
string A4;
string A5;
String A6;
String A7;
String A8;


A1 = Console.ReadLine();
A2 = Console.ReadLine();
A3 = Console.ReadLine();
A4 = Console.ReadLine();
A5 = Console.ReadLine();
A6 = Console.ReadLine();
A7 = Console.ReadLine();
A8 = Console.ReadLine();

Console.Write("Segunda: {0}, {1}, {2}, {3}", A1, A2, A3, A4);
Console.ReadLine();
Console.Write("Terça: {4}, {7}, {5}, {1}, {6}", A5, A8, A6, A2, A7); 

Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: Ao fazer o debug, poste o código de onde a exceção foi acionada, assim, poderemos apontar o problema. Pela msg de erro, o problema está em um dos parâmetros que passou pra alguma função, ou um valor negativo, ou um valor maior que o permitido.

Comment: Passa mais informações, Como o debug mostrada acima, Ou o trecho dos seu código que gera essa exception, Só a mensagem de erro esta muito vago.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

O problem a é que você colocou número do [argumento](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/32448/101) que não existe. Esse números dentro das chaves é o número na ordem que vem argumentos depois do texto de formatação. O primeiro sempre será 0 e vai, 1, 2, e assim por diante quantos tiver, então o último será a quantidade de argumentos passadas menos 1. Se passou 4, eles vão de 0 à 3. Não pode usar os números que usou. O erro ocorreu porque ele não encontrou um argumento de número 4. A *string* de formatação está com problemas nesse contexto, por isso gera uma exceção em tempo de execução.

Mas podemos fazer de forma mais simples e evitar esse erro. Podemos modernizar esse código simplificando-o bastante. Não precisa declarar a variável antes de atribuir um valor pra ela, não precisa dizer o tipo dela, e não precisa passar argumentos depois da *string* de formatação.

Use [`var`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/47383/101) para fazer inferência, [`using static`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/135423/101) para importar a classe estática, e [interpolação de *string*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/91117/101) para usar argumentos dentro da *string*. Assim fica melhor:

```
using static System.Console;

public class Program {
    public static void Main() {
        var A1 = ReadLine();
        var A2 = ReadLine();
        var A3 = ReadLine();
        var A4 = ReadLine();
        var A5 = ReadLine();
        var A6 = ReadLine();
        var A7 = ReadLine();
        var A8 = ReadLine();
        Write($"Segunda: {A1}, {A2}, {A3}, {A4}");
        ReadLine();
        Write($"Terça: {A5}, {A8}, {A6}, {A2}, {A7}");
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/HtXXjp). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/pzeTh9). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/bigown/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Console/StringFormat.cs).

Answer (score 4):

Seu erro esta nesta linha:

```
Console.Write("Terça: {4}, {7}, {5}, {1}, {6}", A5, A8, A6, A2, A7);
```

Os índices neste `Console.Write` devem começar em 0 e ir até no máximo o número de parâmetros menos 1. Para corrigir, basta trocar os índices dos parametros da escrita, assim:

```
Console.Write("Terça: {0}, {1}, {2}, {3}, {4}", A5, A8, A6, A2, A7);
```