# Como quebrar linhas (console mode)?

Tags: c#, .net, string, console

Como eu quebro linhas em C#, tipo se eu por dois comandos `Write` o console vai imprimi-los lado a lado, como faço para imprimir na linha de baixo.

Ps: Código abaixo

```
        var A1 = Console.ReadLine();
        var A2 = Console.ReadLine();
        var A3 = Console.ReadLine();
        var A4 = Console.ReadLine();
        var A5 = Console.ReadLine();
        var A6 = Console.ReadLine();
        var A7 = Console.ReadLine();
        var A8 = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.Write("Segunda :{0}, {1}, {2}, {3},", A1, A8, A4, A5);
        Console.Write("Terça :{0}, {1}, {2}, {3},", A2, A7, A3, A6);
        Console.ReadKey();
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Você tem basicamente três técnicas.

Uma é usar o próprio método para pular a linha. Na maior parte das vezes é a melhor solução. Basta usar o [`WriteLine()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.writeline?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-5.0#overloads), nas suas diversas variações.

```
WriteLine($"Segunda: {A1}, {A8}, {A4}, {3},");
WriteLine($"Terça: {A2}, {A7}, {A3}, {A6},");
```

Pode inclusive [só pular a linha](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.writeline?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-5.0#System_Console_WriteLine):

```
WriteLine();
```

A outra técnica que pode evitar a chamada desse método é colocar um caractere de controle no texto dizendo para pular a linha. Este caractere é o `\n`. Ele será substituído pela quebra de linha.

```
Write($"Segunda: {A1}, {A8}, {A4}, {3},\n");
Write($"Terça: {A2}, {A7}, {A3}, {A6}\n");
```

Ou onde faz mais sentido:

```
Write($"Segunda: {A1}, {A8}, {A4}, {3},\nTerça: {A2}, {A7}, {A3}, {A6}\n");
```

É importante notar que isso não deve ser abusado. Neste exemplo o ideal seria usar outro método mesmo. Fica mais legível.

A outra técnica é pular a linha no próprio código, para isto é necessário indicar que o texto será bruto, ou seja, ele deve ser usado do jeito que está no código. Isto se obtém com o [indicador de verbatim (`@`)](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/41166/101):

```
Write($@"Segunda: {A1}, {A8}, {A4}, {3},
Terça: {A2}, {A7}, {A3}, {A6}\n");
```

Veja que usei [interpolação de *string*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/91117/101) para tornar o código mais fluido.

Também [importei a classe estática](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/135423/101) para não ficar digitando `Console` o tempo todo.

```
using static System.Console;

public class Program {
    public static void Main() {
        var A1 = ReadLine();
        var A2 = ReadLine();
        var A3 = ReadLine();
        var A4 = ReadLine();
        var A5 = ReadLine();
        var A6 = ReadLine();
        var A7 = ReadLine();
        var A8 = ReadLine();
        WriteLine($"Segunda: {A1}, {A8}, {A4}, {3},");
        WriteLine($"Terça: {A2}, {A7}, {A3}, {A6},");
        Write($"Segunda: {A1}, {A8}, {A4}, {3},");
        WriteLine();
        Write($"Terça: {A2}, {A7}, {A3}, {A6},");
        Write($"Segunda: {A1}, {A8}, {A4}, {3},\nTerça: {A2}, {A7}, {A3}, {A6}\n");
        Write($@"Segunda: {A1}, {A8}, {A4}, {3},
    Terça: {A2}, {A7}, {A3}, {A6}\n");
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/Rtlvl4). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/4MugyY). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/bigown/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Console/BreakLine.cs).

Answer (score 10):

Use WriteLine

```
Console.WriteLine("Segunda :{0}, {1}, {2}, {3},", A1, A8, A4, A5);
Console.WriteLine("Terça :{0}, {1}, {2}, {3},", A2, A7, A3, A6);
```