# Visualização incorreta de itens em código POO em C#

Tags: c#, .net, orientação-a-objetos

Meu código ele precisa receber os valores de três livros que são código, título, autor, editora e valor. Só que a visualização está confusa.

### A impressão que fica

> ```
> nome do livro 0: q // Devia mostrar livro 1 Digite o autor do livro 0:
> w // Devia mostrar livro 1 Digite a editora do livro 0: e // Devia
> mostrar livro 1 Digite o valor do livro 0: 12.12 // Devia mostrar
> livro 1
>
> Digite o código do livro 0: 89 // Devia mostrar livro 2 Digite o nome
> do livro 0: a // Devia mostrar livro 2 Digite o autor do livro 0: s //
> Devia mostrar livro 2 Digite a editora do livro 0: // Devia mostrar
> livro 2 Digite o valor do livro 0: 34.67 // Devia mostrar livro 2
>
> Digite o código do livro 0: 98 // Devia mostrar livro 3 Digite o nome
> do livro 0: t // Devia mostrar livro 3 Digite o autor do livro 0: y //
> Devia mostrar livro 3 Digite a editora do livro 0: h // Devia mostrar
> livro 3 Digite o valor do livro 0: 32.54 // Devia mostrar livro 3
>
> Novo interessado Novo interessado Novo interessado
>
> 76 q w e 1212 1 // Devia mostra o index do primeiro livro
>
> 89 a s d 3467 1 // Devia mostra o index do segundo livro
>
> 98 t y h 3254 1 // Devia mostra o index do terceiro livro
> ```

### A impressão desejada

> ```
> Digite o código do livro 1: 76 Digite o nome do livro 1: q Digite o autor do livro 1: w Digite a editora do
> livro 1: e Digite o valor do livro 1: 12.12
>
> Digite o código do livro 2: 89 Digite o nome do livro 2: a Digite o
> autor do livro 2: s Digite a editora do livro 2: d Digite o valor do
> livro 2: 34.67
>
> Digite o código do livro 3: 98 Digite o nome do livro 3: t Digite o
> autor do livro 3: y Digite a editora do livro 3: h Digite o valor do
> livro 3: 32.54
>
> Novo interessado Novo interessado Novo interessado
>
> 76 q w e 1212 1 // Livro1
>
> 89 a s d 3467 2 // Livro 2
>
> 98 t y h 3254 3 // Livro3
> ```

```
using System;

namespace POO1
{
    public class Livro
    {
        public int codigo;
        public string autor;
        public string titulo;
        public string editora;
        public double valor;
        public int interessados;

        public void NovoInteressado()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Novo interessado");
            interessados++;
        }

        public void ImprimirDadosLivro()
        {
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine(codigo);
            Console.WriteLine(titulo);
            Console.WriteLine(autor);
            Console.WriteLine(editora);
            Console.WriteLine(valor);
            Console.WriteLine(interessados);
        }

        public class AppLivro
        {
            static int Main(string[] args)
            {
                Livro livro1 = new Livro();
                Livro livro2 = new Livro();
                Livro livro3 = new Livro();

                Console.Write($"Digite o código do livro {livro1.interessados}: ");
                livro1.codigo = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                Console.Write($"Digite o nome do livro {livro1.interessados}: ");
                livro1.titulo = Convert.ToString(Console.ReadLine());
                Console.Write($"Digite o autor do livro {livro1.interessados}: ");
                livro1.autor = Convert.ToString(Console.ReadLine());
                Console.Write($"Digite a editora do livro {livro1.interessados}: ");
                livro1.editora = Convert.ToString(Console.ReadLine());
                Console.Write($"Digite o valor do livro {livro1.interessados}: ");
                livro1.valor = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

                Console.WriteLine();

                Console.Write($"Digite o código do livro {livro2.interessados}: ");
                livro2.codigo = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                Console.Write($"Digite o nome do livro {livro2.interessados}: ");
                livro2.titulo = Convert.ToString(Console.ReadLine());
                Console.Write($"Digite o autor do livro {livro2.interessados}: ");
                livro2.autor = Convert.ToString(Console.ReadLine());
                Console.Write($"Digite a editora do livro {livro2.interessados}: ");
                livro2.editora = Convert.ToString(Console.ReadLine());
                Console.Write($"Digite o valor do livro {livro2.interessados}: ");
                livro2.valor = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

                Console.WriteLine();

                Console.Write($"Digite o código do livro {livro3.interessados}: ");
                livro3.codigo = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                Console.Write($"Digite o nome do livro {livro3.interessados}: ");
                livro3.titulo = Convert.ToString(Console.ReadLine());
                Console.Write($"Digite o autor do livro {livro3.interessados}: ");
                livro3.autor = Convert.ToString(Console.ReadLine());
                Console.Write($"Digite a editora do livro {livro3.interessados}: ");
                livro3.editora = Convert.ToString(Console.ReadLine());
                Console.Write($"Digite o valor do livro {livro3.interessados}: ");
                livro3.valor = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

                Console.WriteLine();

                livro1.NovoInteressado();
                livro2.NovoInteressado();
                livro3.NovoInteressado();

                livro1.ImprimirDadosLivro();
                livro2.ImprimirDadosLivro();
                livro3.ImprimirDadosLivro();
                Console.ReadKey();
                return 0;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O código tem vários problemas, especialmente se está querendo aprender sobre orientação a objetos. Esse código mistura responsabilidades (imprimir e controlar dados, talvez até algo a mais) e [inicializa um objeto em estado inválido](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/73530/101). Note que eu mudei muito o código, algumas coisas só pra ficar mais organizado e com estilo mais moderno de como se escrever C#.

Corrigi o erro de tentar converter coisas que podem dar erro e quebrar a aplicação. O ideal é tratar o erro de forma mais sofisticada, mas eu fiz apenas encerrar a aplicação, pode melhor isto. Tirei conversão que não faz o menor sentido, não se converte um tipo para ele mesmo.

Também troquei o tipo do valor que é inadequado para valores monetários.

Não corrigi pequenos erros de lógica que não causam maiores dificuldades.

Outra grande melhoria foi eliminar a repetição de código, ou se faz um laço ou uma função que lide com isso, eu preferi uma função, mas se quiser troque para um laço, é fácil.

O erro que está cometendo é que está imprimindo uma informação que nada tem a ver com a descrição. Se deseja imprimir o número do livro que está entrando então esse controle tem que ser feito nessa lógica e não no objeto. A descrição é bem clara que deseja uma ordem de entrada e não a quantidade de interessados naquele livro. Mudei isso, mas não é a forma ideal, me parece que dizer qual é a ordem nem faz sentido aí, pede os dados do livro e boa, mas resolvi o que queria. Claro que a mensagem poderia ser outra, mas não tenho como adivinhar se for o caso.

Essa ideia de interessados não está clara pra mim, se for o que eu estou pensando então a lógica está inadequada, cadastrar um livro é uma coisa, ter um interessado nele é outra coisa. Mas pode ser tantas outras coisas, porque não tem uma definição do que isso quer dizer e código não deixa claro também, eu teria que especular muito, mas em qualquer caso parece algo errado.

Então não consegui resolver a outra questão da impressão, Isto é um código? É a ordem mesmo? Se é a ordem onde ela é armazenada? Você não pode imprimir algo que não está armazenado em lugar algum. Está mandando imprimir a quantidade de interessados, então está certo. Se não faz o que espera então o conceito está confuso. Com o conceito errado o código sempre estará errado, Primeiro conceitue certo para depois ter uma solução adequada. No que foi postado só dá para resolver esse parte.

```
using static System.Console;

namespace POO1 {
    public class AppLivro {
        static int Main(string[] args) {
            var livro1 = new Livro();
            if (!PegaDados(livro1, 1)) return 1;
            var livro2 = new Livro();
            if (!PegaDados(livro2, 2)) return 1;
            var livro3 = new Livro();
            if (!PegaDados(livro3, 3)) return 1;
            livro1.NovoInteressado();
            livro2.NovoInteressado();
            livro3.NovoInteressado();
            livro1.Imprimir();
            livro2.Imprimir();
            livro3.Imprimir();
            return 0;
        }
        private static bool PegaDados(Livro livro, int ordem) {
            Write($"Digite o código do livro {ordem}: ");
            if (!int.TryParse(ReadLine(), out livro.codigo)) return false;
            Write($"Digite o nome do livro {ordem}: ");
            livro.titulo = ReadLine();
            Write($"Digite o autor do livro {ordem}: ");
            livro.autor = ReadLine();
            Write($"Digite a editora do livro {ordem}: ");
            livro.editora = ReadLine();
            Write($"Digite o valor do livro {ordem}: ");
            if (!decimal.TryParse(ReadLine(), out livro.valor)) return false;
            WriteLine();
            return true;
        }
    }
    public class Livro {
        public int codigo;
        public string autor;
        public string titulo;
        public string editora;
        public decimal valor;
        public int interessados;
        public void NovoInteressado() {
            WriteLine("Novo interessado");
            interessados++;
        }
        public void Imprimir() {
            WriteLine();
            WriteLine(codigo);
            WriteLine(titulo);
            WriteLine(autor);
            WriteLine(editora);
            WriteLine(valor);
            WriteLine(interessados);
        }
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/6JuBe1). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/4rCwWa). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Algorithm/PrintData.cs).

Comment: Obrigado pela explicação.

Comment: O que siginifica as linhas `if (!int.TryParse(ReadLine(), out livro.codigo)) return false;` e `if (!PegaDados(livro1, 1)) return 1;`?

Comment: Eu sei que tem outras parecidas, mas explicando essas as outras parecidas são automaticamente explicadas também

Comment: `using static System.Console;` ele dispensa a necessidade de qualificar o acesso com nome do tipo?

Comment: Veja https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/16089/101 e https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/135423/101. Quase tudo o que quiser saber já tem no site, só procurar, o que não tiver abra uma pergunta nova e respondemos.

Comment: o que a linha `private static bool PegaDados(Livro livro, int ordem)` significa?

Comment: Eu não sabia que você tinha dificuldade com coisas tão básicas, seria melhor estudar cada detalhe. Eu achei que por estar querendo fazer algo orientado a objeto que é algo avançado indicava que já conhecia o básico, mas agora vejo que ainda falta o fundamento. Comece fazer coisas mais básicas, aprenda uma coisa de cada vez, e esqueça OOP, isso só vai atrapalhar sua evolução. Quando dominar o básico aí terá condições de partir para algo mais sofisticado. Se pular etapas como estava fazendo não vai aprender nada direito, só decorará receitas de bolo sem entender o que está acontecendo.