# Atalho para o comando Console.WriteLine em C#, existe?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, ide

Sei que no Java existe o comando "Sout" e depois aperta em *backspace* e ele já gera a linha de código.

Comment: Está usando o Visual studio?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9613685/how-to-make-a-shortcut-for-console-writeline

Comment: A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo (quando tiver 15 pontos).

Answer (score 4):

Não faz sentido ter um atalho na linguagem. Java também não tem, poderia ter em um IDE e aí depende de qual está usando.

Se estiver usando o Visual Studio você pode invocar um *snippet* chamado `cw` que logo após digitá-lo no editor e acionar o <kbd>TAB</kbd> ele expande para o que você quer.

Note que você pode simplificar o comando com um `using static`. Veja mais em [Qual é a diferença entre o "using" e o "using static"?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/135423/101).

Se nada disso servir, poderia criar você um código para ter uma função mais curta abstraindo a função original. Não recomendo isso, e, portanto, não colocarei exemplo.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conceptual.md).

Answer (score -4):

No Visual Studio, pode-se utilizar **"cw"** para chamar o Console.WriteLine();

Comment: Boas-vindas Danilo. A intenção de ajudar é boa, mas sobre o `cw`, isso já foi explicado na outra [resposta](/a/460304/3635). No entanto se tiver algum detalhe que complemente, ou que fale algo diferente, você pode [edit] a sua resposta atual. Para atuar em futuras perguntas é importante ler [**finalidade do Stack Overflow em Português**](/help) e se atentar se a pergunta não é um [caso de fechamento](/help/closed-questions) ao invés de responder. *Agradecemos a compreensão*.